# Execute scalar function inside stored procedure SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, user-defined-functions

I have created a scalar function in order to calculate amortization value. I want to insert that value in table with stored procedure, but when I execute procedure, I don't get the value from function, but when I execute the function outside procedure I get the correct value. Can someone help me and describe what I'm doing wrong?

Code sample for procedure is:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [FixedAssets].[SetAmortizationValue]
(
        @FixedAssetID int
        )
    AS
    BEGIN
    DECLARE
    @AmortizationMethodID int,
    @PurchaseCost decimal,
    @ResidualValue decimal,
    @AmortizationGroupID int,
    @AmortizationValue decimal,
    @GLValue decimal;


select @AmortizationMethodID = ( select AmortizationMethodID from FixedAssets.AmortizationMethod 
                                                        where AmortizationMethodID = ( select AmortizationMethodID from FixedAssets.FixedAsset where FixedAssetID = @FixedAssetID ))

select
    @PurchaseCost = PurchaseValue,
    @AmortizationGroupID = AmortizationGroupID,
    @ResidualValue = ResidualValue
    from FixedAssets.FixedAsset where FixedAssetID = @FixedAssetID;

set @AmortizationValue = FixedAssets.ufnAmortizationValue(@FixedAssetID,@AmortizationMethodID) 

set @GLValue = FixedAssets.ufnCalculateGLValue(@FixedAssetID)


INSERT INTO FixedAssets.FixedAssetAmortization
(
     FixedAssetID
    ,PurchaseCost
    ,ResidualValue
    ,AmortizationValue
    ,AmortizationGroupID
    ,GLValue
)
VALUES
(
    @FixedAssetID
    ,@PurchaseCost
    ,@ResidualValue
    ,@AmortizationValue
    ,@AmortizationGroupID
    ,@GLValue
);

END;
```

Code sample for one of the functions that I want to execute is:

```
-- select FixedAssets.ufnAmortizationValue(15,1);

ALTER function [FixedAssets].[ufnAmortizationValue] (
    @FixedAssetID int,
    @AmortizationMethodID int
)

returns decimal(9, 2)
as
begin
    declare
    
       @PurchaseValue decimal (9,2),
       @AmortizationValue decimal(9, 2);


select @PurchaseValue = ( select PurchaseValue from FixedAssets.FixedAsset where FixedAssetID = @FixedAssetID );
                                 

select @AmortizationValue =     
                                case
                                    when @AmortizationMethodID = 1 then( select (PurchaseValue - ResidualValue) /EstimatedUsefulLife from FixedAssets.FixedAsset where FixedAssetID = @FixedAssetID)
                                    when @AmortizationMethodID = 2 then @PurchaseValue * ( 
                                                                            select DepreciationPercent / 100 from FixedAssets.AmortizationGroup
                                                                            where AmortizationGroupID = (select AmortizationGroupID from FixedAssets.FixedAsset where FixedAssetID = @FixedAssetID)
                                                                        )
                                end;  

return @AmortizationValue
end;
```

Comment: `exec` is for calling stored procedures, not functions. To call a function use `select @var=function()`

Comment: If you would like to execute the scalar function, remove the parentheses (): `exec @AmortizationValue = FixedAssets.ufnAmortizationValue @FixedAssetID,@AmortizationMethodID`

Comment: @VladimirBaranov..scalar functions are “executed”..you cannot grant select permission on a scalar function, you grant execute

Comment: You could, and should, change to be a table-valued function.

Comment: You don't use `EXEC` against a scalar function though, @Iptr . It's not `EXEC GETDATE`; that would return an error that the stored procedure `GETDATE` is not found. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/uBQvND7H)

Comment: Though, yes, you *can* use the syntax you state against a **user** defined scalar function, @Iptr that doesn't make your statement correct, as you *can* reference a scalar function in a `SELECT`, or even in a `SET` [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/FL2cya3A)

Comment: "when I execute procedure, I don't get the value from function" we can't test this as we don't have sample table structures. Maybe construct a https://dbfiddle.uk so we can test it